# Threejs JSONLoader and OOP, how to attach model to scene (from loader callback)

Tags: javascript, oop, three.js

I want to use the THREE JSONLoader in a "Scenemanager" Object that handles all the adding and removing of objects and models, basically to learn OOP, JS and Threejs.

I create the App3D (which manages the scene) and load call the App3D function that should load the resource with the according path and add it to the scene and the objects array which are defined in the constructor. I always get an undefined when I use `this.scene` and I guess I am missing a basic OOP / JS concept of how enclosures work. Any help appreceated.

app.js

```
window.onload = () => {

  let app = new App3D(); 
  app.loadModel('/assets/models/model.json');

}
```

in the app3D I do all the initialising of Threejs, add the scene, lights, camera and renderer and an array actors that stores all added object

app3D.js

```
class App3D{
  constructor() {
    this.loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.objects = [];

    this.createScene();
  }

  createScene(){
    // does all the camera and renderer initialzation etc
  }

  loadModel(model){
    this.loader.load(model, function(geometry, materials){
      let material = new THREE.MultiMaterial( materials );
      let mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
      this.scene.add(mesh);
      this.objects.push(mesh);
    });
  }

  render() {
   // request animation frame render etc
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you're using both arrow functions `() => { ... }` and classic functions `function () { ... }`, you'll want to read a little about the differences between them, especially where `this` is concerned. [Further reading](https://medium.com/@_bengarrison/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4).

With an arrow function, `this` comes from the context where the function was defined:

```
class Foo {
  constructor (el) {
    var foo = this;
    el.addEventListener('click', () => {
      // foo === this
    });
  }
}
```

With a classic function, `this` comes from the calling object, and so for event listeners you typically need to bind the function or store `this` in the outside scope.

```
class Foo {
  constructor (el) {
    var foo = this;
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
      // foo !== this
    });
  }
}
```

—

```
class Foo {
  constructor (el) {
    var foo = this;
    el.addEventListener('click', function () {
      // foo === this
    }.bind(this));
  }
}
```

In your `loadModel` function, you need to store or bind `this` in one of the ways above.

Comment: Many thanks, that was exactly what I was missing and .bind(this) solved it.